# Problem with Skype in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, troubleshooting, skype, webcam

Ever since I upgraded my MacBook Pro from Leopard to Snow Leopard I have always had problems with Skype.

When I start a video chat, Skype tells me that my camera is not installed on the machine (even though it clearly is). After searching the internet I have found some 'solutions' but none of them work. After trying them, it makes my camera feed appear as a blank, green image.

How can I get Skype to function with the built in iSight with Snow Leopard properly?

is there any body else face this problem?

Comment: do you have the latest version of skype?

Comment: Yes I have the last version.

Comment: Does the camera work in other iSight-aware apps, like 'Photo Booth' or 'iChat'?

Comment: yes it's work there.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, check out this fix from the Skype Forums;

1. Close Skype go to
2. /Library/QuickTime/ DELETE this
3. file: CamCamX5.component Open and
4. login skype ;-)

Please give credit to our french brothers:

Credit to our our french brothers  :0)

[Click here to be taken to the original forum listing](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?s=8beaef30c61bd476bcef3d8b0931f858&showtopic=414141&view=findpost&p=1944041)

Comment: I don't have such a file in my /Library/QuickTime